# Redirect for missing images with specific filename

Tags: image, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect all requests for an image called my_image.gif, when it's requested from any subdirectory of /images/, to /other_dir/my_image.gif. So /images/foo/my_image.gif, /images/bar/my_image.gif etc would all go to /other_dir/my_image.gif but all other images in /images/ (and its subdirectories) would be unaffected.

I don't know if this makes a difference, but my_image.gif will never actually exist in /images/ or any of its subdirectories.

Is there an easy way to do this with .htaccess? I can only seem to find ways to redirect all missing images.

Comment: This should be moved to Server Fault. Stackoverflow is for programming questions and this doesn't require programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using mod_rewrite you should add this to your .htaccess, for more info check out the [manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule ^/images/my_image\.gif$ /other_dir/my_image.gif
```

Comment: Your answer is better. Editing answer to use a capturing group for the file name.

Comment: Thanks JKirchartz, and sorry for my very slow reply - my first time posting here and didn't realised I didn't have email alerts switched on!

Comment: @FrankHarrison btw, if you wanna gain rep and increase your chances of people answering your questions you should accept answers when appropriate http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work